# Exempt one xml attribute to be converted into a string when JSON result is returned

Tags: json, xml, xml2js

I am using xml2js module of npm. 
It converts my xml to JSON.
Suppose my xml is

```
<root>
    <fname>Akhil</fname>
    <lname>Sahni</lname>
    <timestamp>ISODate("2016-08-31T13:18:57.050Z")</timestamp>
</root>
```

so it returns me a JSON object as

```
{
  "fname":"Akhil",
  "lname":"Sahni",
  "timestamp" : "ISODate("2016-07-21T13:20:59.311Z")"
}
```

Note that the time stamp is a literal string with open/close quote problems.
I want my JSON to be

```
{
  "fname":"Akhil",
  "lname":"Sahni",
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-07-21T13:20:59.311Z")
}
```

ISODate is now a descriptor.

Comment: Can someone tell me how to achieve this case

Comment: It's not clear what your question is exactly (or what you've tried, and what doesn't work).

Comment: Fix code formatting.